# How can I create a service in Flask?

Tags: python, flask

I have to make this endpoints por my api or service: addition just returns the addition of `a` and `b` and the same thing with de division. The last route has to return in a json format with the json which was send by url.

`addition/{a}/{b}` , `division/{a}/{b}`, and
  `url/json`

How can I get multiple parameters from a URL using that way. I've already know this way ->

```
@app.route('/api/addition/', methods=['GET'])
def add():
  a = request.args.get('a')
  b = request.args.get('b')
  (... some stuff ...)
```

is any other way to do it?

Thanks for your help, sorry English is nor my first language, maybe I made some grammar mistake. I apologize about that.
viviramji.

Comment: `@app.route('/api/addition/<int:a>/<int:b>')` and `def add(a, b)` I think.

Comment: As you want to make an API, I suggest you use [flask_restful](https://flask-restful.readthedocs.io/en/latest/), which is a better tool to make APIs.

Answer (score 0):

This might help.

## Note this is a `POST` request `Flask` API.

You can send custom data and operation of any type you want. you can test the following code with `postman`. Make sure the raw data you send from `postman` is `application/json` type.

```
from flask import Flask, url_for, json,request, Response, jsonify
app = Flask(__name__)
@app.route('/api/addition/', methods=['POST'])
def add():
    requestJson = request.json
    
    print(requestJson)
    val1 = requestJson['val1']
    val2 = requestJson['val2']
    operation = requestJson['operation']
    respDict = {"Message":None,"Value":None}
    if operation.lower() == "addition":
        val = val1 + val2
        respDict['Message']="addition"
    if operation.lower() == "division":
        respDict['Message']="division"
        val = val1/val2
    
    respDict['Value']=val
    resp = Response(json.dumps(respDict), status = 200)
    return resp

import sys
if __name__ == '__main__':
    if(len(sys.argv) > 1):
        portString = sys.argv[1]
    else:
        portString = "5200"
    app.run(
        host = "0.0.0.0",
        port=int(portString),
        debug=True,
        threaded = True)
```

Here is the `requestJson`

```
{
    "val1":3,
    "val2":2,
    "operation":"addition"
}
```

Disclaimer: This not might exactly answer your question but solves your problem.

Comment: That answer does not solve OP's problem. He wants to use the route to pass arguments. You are catching request data and not proper arguments, defining the route. Plus, you are defining an API and not showing the URL you are calling for when showing your result.

Answer (score 0):

You can create a route that accepts the two values, along with the desired operation type:

```
import operator

@app.route('/api/<operation>/<a>/<b>', methods=['GET'])
def perform_operation(operation, a, b):
   _ops = {'addition':operator.add, 'subtraction':operator.sub, 'multiplication':operator.mul, 'division':operator.truediv}
   if operation not in _ops:
     return flask.jsonify({'success':False})
   return flask.jsonify({'success':True, 'result':_ops[operation](float(a), float(b))})
```